# Is it possible to make a vertical slider in Qualtrics?

Tags: slider, qualtrics

The documentation of slider questions within Qualtrics can be found [here](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/editing-questions/question-types-guide/standard-content/slider/), but there is no mention of being able to have the slider run vertically as opposed to horizontally in the page. Does anyone know if it's possible to have the slider run vertically in the question block?

Answer (score 1):

Not with a Slider question.  There is a Graphical Slider question type that has the option of vertical sliders, but it also contains graphics.